# What can I do with a polynomial of cosines?

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials

In a mathematical derivation I ended up with a polynomial of the form:

$\cos^3\theta + a_1cos^2\ \theta + a_2cos\ \theta + a_3= 0$

Coefficients $a_n$ are not functions of $\theta$ (but are not known constants either, so they remain symbolic).

1. Is there a name for this polynomial?
2. Is it possible to derive a formula for all roots/ $ \theta $'s that satisfy this equation? Or is this the closest I'll get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [trigonometric polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_polynomial).

For your question, to solve for $\theta$, first solve for the root of $x^3 + a_1 x^2+a_2x + a_3=0$, then solve for $\cos \theta = x$.

Comment: Thanks, what if the $ a_n $ are not known, but are not functions of $ \theta $. What's the best way to find the roots?

Comment: a famous formula for cubic is cardano formula. Find the root, check the magnitude of solution to see if it is at most $1$, take cosine inverse, don't forget that cosine has multiple solution.